# How to use JavaScript/jQuery to search/delete emails in GMail, HotMail etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a small software which is used for deleting all old emails which was sent by a specific/particular user, (e.g.) GroupOn.

I would like to run this program on multiple platforms and hence I would like to Code it in JavaScript.

I am not sure whether it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is it possible" is a little too vague to count as a good question.  I'm surprised you got legitimate answers at all.

Comment: And you know, Javascript isn't the only technology that can run on multiple platforms.

Comment: @djechlin: I was tempted to just give a "Yes", but minimum character limit forced me to expand it to a proper answer.

Comment: @djechlin , thank you for reminding me. I have updated my subject. Please provide valuable answers if you could. cheers

Comment: Okay, now it's just a bad question because you're asking us to write or architect a large application for you.  [ask], [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with pure client-side JavaScript. You will probably want to implement this using [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol).

There is an [IMAP library in JavaScript](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap), but it is server-side (it's built on node.js).

Comment: Why not?  Can't client-side JS open an IMAP connection?

Comment: @djechlin No, for a couple of reasons. There's the same-origin policy that would inhibit things, and also there's no mechanism in client side JavaScript to communicate via SSL.

Comment: @PeterOlson, I agree with you, but I still want to give a try

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible using [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (or similar tools in other browsers), you can inject any JavaScript code into an existing website. See [UserScripts.org](https://userscripts.org/) for a bunch of examples of what you can do with GreaseMonkey.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm going to give a try.

Comment: wa, this question has been closed

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Google APIs (something else for Hotmail etc.) to be able to do that. You may be able to call/consume those APIs through REST and Javascript/JQuery. I don't think there is any way of doing it with plain Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: alright, thank you anyway

Comment: I did found the Google Gmail API, I'll give it a try tonight.